# Makehuman facial rig in Blender

Tags: rigging

I have a Makehuman model fully rigged with the default rig and have imported it into Blender and everything seems to work fine. I have quite a complex pose I'm happy with except the face. My character looks like they're watching grass grow. I want a smile of some sort.

I've tried rotating bones but can't get any sort of decent facial expression.

What bones to move for expressions, a smile for instance? I can't find anything useful online.  What is the mechanism for controlling facial expressions in a Rigified MakeHuman model?

Or can I delete all the face bones and replace them with something more intuitive?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos There is enough detail to answer this question, but you have to be familiar with MakeHuman's face rig.  The basic problem is that the OP needs to enable a MakeHuman feature to get a face control panel.

Comment: You need to enable the MakeHuman Face control panel.  Select the generated rig, go to the rig layers, and SHIFT-Left-Click on Rig layer 2 to enable it.  You then use the control panel to control facial gestures.

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks for clarifying, reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to control the face in a MakeHuman model that has been rigified, you need to enable the Face control panel.  For unknown reasons, it is hidden by default.

To make the Face control panel visible, select the generated rig, go to the Armature *Object Data Properties* tab and add Armature Layer 2 to the selected armature layers (Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> Left Click):

[image: Armature Object Data Properties with Armature Layer 2 highlighted]

(Layers are counted from 0.)